# How to get PostgreSQL database size from Python?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 to get a PostgreSQL database size in Python3.

```
dbname = 'my_pg_database'
q = 'select pg_total_relation_size(%s);'
conn.cursor.execute(q, (dbname, ))
row = conn.cursor.fetchone()
print(str(row[0]))
```

I have also tried with the same code but switching second line:

```
q = 'select pg_total_relation_size((%s));'
```

And changing second and third lines:

```
dbname = 'my_pg_database'
q = 'select pg_total_relation_size({dbname});'.format(dbname=dbname)
conn.cursor.execute(q)
row = conn.cursor.fetchone()
print(str(row[0]))
```

I always get the same syntax error, I had a lot this problem before with other queries, but I managed to deal with this using format or the other way, but not in this case. Anyone knows why?

**EDIT**

The errors I am getting are:

With the first code:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "my_pg_database" does not exist
>   LINE 1: select pg_total_relation_size('my_pg_database');

By the way, here there is a kind of arrow pointing to the first quote of the second line.

With the third code:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "my_pg_database" does not exist
>   LINE 1: select pg_total_relation_size(my_pg_database);

And here there is a kind of arrow pointing to the m of my_pg_database of the second line.

Note that the first error is talking about relation and the second one about column.

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3 - `print(things, you, want, to print)` not `print things you want to print` (note the parenthesis)

Comment: OK in fact I am not using print (logger instead), but the problem is in the query, sure. But I am going to change that here!

Comment: Can you provide the error that you are getting?

Comment: I edited the post with the errors.

Comment: You're using the wrong function, you need pg_database_size() to get the size of your database. pg_total_relation_size() is for a single table and it's indexes.

Comment: @Frank I was just going to post that as an answer. So post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong function, you need pg_database_size() to get the size of your database. pg_total_relation_size() is for a single table and it's indexes.

Check the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT) for more details.